# Je ne pense pas que ni elle ni moi n'avions anticipé que cet accord comprendrait les enterrements, mais

Tags: sens, négation

Bonjour,

*The Truth* de Savannah Brown :

> Quoi qu'il en soit, on avait passé un accord tacite dans le but de
> terminer nos études sécondaires l'une à côté de l'autre ; **je ne
> pense pas que ni elle ni moi n'avions anticipé** que cet accord
> comprendrait les enterrements, **mais** elle était venue et, même si
> je n'avais aucune intention de le lui dire, je lui en étais
> reconnaissante.

Donc, *je ne pense pas que ni elle ni moi n'avions anticipé que*... = *je ne pense pas que nous n'avions pas anticipé que*... = *je pense que nous avions anticipé que*... Si c'est correct, quel est le rôle du "mais" ?

Comment: Comme il n'y a pas de *pas* après le *n'*, *n'* est différent *ne*, *n'* remplace *nous* :  je ne pense pas que ***, ni elle ni moi, n**ous* avions anticipé. Le pas que vous utilisez dans votre raccourci concerne le verbe *penser* pas *anticiper* (explication non académique, mais que fonctionne)

Comment: @Personne _n' remplace nous_ --- Ça se pourrait, mais pourquoi alors ne pas écrire "nous", tout simplement ? Mais imaginons que c'est le cas, pourquoi ne pas utiliser le subjonctif après "je ne pense pas" ? Je pense comme jlliagre que c'est  une erreur de traduction.

Comment: « je ne pense pas que , ***ni elle ni moi, n***ous avions anticipé que … » avec *nous* : « je ne pense pas que, *(ni elle ni moi →) **nous, nous*** avions anticipé que … » ce qui donne « je ne pense pas que, ***nounou*** avions anticipé que … » [*nounou* = baby sitter] … malgré les apparences, ce n'est pas capillotracté, c'est une question d'oreille, de musicalité du français auxquelles l'oralité du quotidien est sensible … c'est le domaine de l'Oulipo https://www.oulipo.net/ … pas celui de M Grevisse !

Comment: @jlliagre … « On peut “violer” la grammaire … *à condition* de lui faire de beaux enfants »  formule paternalo-machiste des millénaires passés que je ne fais pas mienne, loin de là … je préfère accompagner la grammaire hors des sentiers battus … si elle y trouve son compte, elle les empruntera :-)

Answer (score 4):

Oui, ton raisonnement est le même que le mien.

|  | 1 |  | 2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | je ne pense pas | que | ni elle ni moi n'avions anticipé | que |
| = | je ne pense pas | que | nous n'avions pas anticipé | que |
| = | je pense | que | nous avions anticipé | que |

Le ***mais*** n'a pas de sens à la suite de cette affirmation puisque qu'il n'y a pas de contradiction entre le fait qu'elles l'aient anticipé et le fait que ce se soit passé.

Je penche donc pour une erreur de traduction.

La phrase gagnerait en logique en évitant cette double négation et en ne la laissant que d'un côté ou de l'autre :

|  | 1 |  | 2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Je pense | que | ni elle ni moi n'avions anticipé | que |
|  | Je ne pense pas | que | l'une d'entre nous ait anticipé | que |

Answer (score 1):

La construction est grammaticalement correcte : on n'utilise pas « pas ». Voici quatre exemples ci-dessous.

[réf. 1, 1952](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_%C3%A9lection_sentimentale/KW8eEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ni+moi+n%27avions+pens%C3%A9%22&pg=PT187&printsec=frontcover) Mais ni lui ni moi n'avions pensé qu'on fourrerait dans ce guêpier la pauvre Simone.

([réf. 2, 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Totem_3_0/3fAADQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ni+moi+n%27avions+pens%C3%A9%22&pg=PT176&printsec=frontcover)) Surtout, ni Chloé ni moi n'avions pensé que l'ennui, lorsqu'on fait du camping, c'est que les possibilités pour recharger son portable son quand mêpe très limitées.

([réf. 3, 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Julie/jJfuDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22ni+moi+n%27avions+pens%C3%A9%22&pg=PT206&printsec=frontcover)) Ni Franziska, ni moi n'avions pensé à ce détail ridicule.

(réf. 4, LBU) J'espère que ni moi ni mes enfants ne verrons ces temps-là (VIGNY, Cinq-
Mars, I).

- (je ne pense pas que) (ni elle ni moi n'avions anticipé que)... = je ne pense pas que nous n'avions pas anticipé que...

Ce n'est pas correct ; le sens de la première construction est déduit de la façon suivante. Il s'agit de la négation d'une conjonction. Cette loi de la logique est appliqué dans le langage (« non (A et B) » est équivalent à  « non A ou non B ». (« non » et « pas » sont interchangeables.)

- ni elle ni moi n'avions anticipé que ==> (Équivalent à ce qui suit, le lecteur doit s'en convaincre.)
- elle n'avait pas anticipé **et** je n'avais pas anticipé que ==> (Dans ce qui suit on ajoute le reste.)
- (je  pense  que)  pas (elle n'avait pas anticipé **et** je n'avais pas anticipé) que ==> (en langage correct dans ce qui va suivre)
- je pense qu'elle avait anticipé  ou que j'avais anticipé que ==> (en langage plus naturel dans ce qui suit)
- je pense que soit l'une soit l'autre de nous deux avait anticipé que

Ceci reviens à la forme suivante (introduction d'une négation double, qui est encore acceptable).

- je ne pense pas que pas une de nous deux  n'avait  anticipé que

Évidemment ce n'est pas équivalent non plus à « je pense que nous avions anticipé que ».

Du point de vue du bon sens associé au texte il y a un problème : si la personne se remémore un passé lointain qui n'est plus très vivant dans sa mémoire, alors il est possible qu'elle ne sache pas très bien si elle avait anticipé le fait donné ou non ; on trouve alors empreint d'assez de bon sens le fait de déclarer qu'il était nécessaire selon un certain raisonnement qu'il y en ait eu une  des deux pour anticiper (c'est à dire au moins une). S'il s'agit d'une situation assez récente dans le passé, alors la personne sait très bien si elle anticipait quelque chose ou non ; dans ce cas la construction ne correspond pas à la réalité puisque elle implique que la personne qui parle ne sait pas à propos de son propre cas.

De toute façon le fait que ces équivalences soient correctes ou non n'a pas d'incidence sur l'utilisation de « mais ».

Voici un contexte similaire où le bon sens est différent et qui est formulé par la même construction (toujours correcte).

- Je ne pensais pas que ni la chaleur ni le temps n'en serait venu à bout, mais je sentais que quel que soit l'agent de la destruction il aurait à agir sur une assez longue période.